# flask python website save user input and add it to the list

Tags: python, flask

this website currently starts out with two input fields at the tope left corner. The first input is the persons name and the second input is the question they have.Currently it just prints successful and unsuccessful. when you press submit button I want the website to print and save the name and question. when a new question is asked it gets added to the list. for example

### Danny: how old are U?
Tom: when's ur birthday?
Ashley : how tall are you ?

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def basic():
# request.method and request.form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['name'] and request.form['pass']:
            return 'Validation successful'
        else:
            return 'Validation unsuccessful'
        return 'Hi'

    return render_template('def.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()



<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="POST">

<input type=text name='name'><br>
<input type=password name='pass'><br>
<input type=submit name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Add it to the user’s *session* data. Pass it to the template and output it there.

Comment: If you don't want now this changes to be persistent, then just create a list outside of function (`user_inputs=[]`) and before the line `return 'Validation successful'` add line to store new input: `user_inputs.append((request.form['name'], request.form['pass']))`. Also note that `return 'Hi'` is never executed and 'pass' is definitely bad name for form field, which contains question and not password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may help to look into [Flask templating](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/), which would allow you to add each response to a list in python, and then re-render the webpage with the new data as shown in this example.

In app.py

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

questions = []
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def basic():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['name'] and request.form['ques']:
           questions.append({'name': request.form['name'], 'question': request.form['ques']})
    return render_template('def.html', questions=questions)

app.run(debug=True)
```

In templates/def.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% for question in questions %}
    {{question.name}}: {{question.question}}<br>
{% endfor %}
<form action="/" method="POST">
Name: <input type=text name='name'><br>
Question: <input type=text name='ques'><br>
<input type=submit name='submit'>
</form>
```

In this example, each time a form is submitted, the questions variable in app.py gets appended to, and then def.html gets re-rendered with the new data.

Comment: thank you so much !! but how come the data goes away when I refresh the page ?is there a way to save it on there forever once the question is asked

Comment: The data should not disappear if you refresh the page or open a new tab. However, it will be lost if the script crashes or is closed. If you want it to be more permanent, I would recommend writing the data to a text file every time it is added to. `with open('myFile.txt', 'a') as f: f.append({'name': request.form['name'], 'question': request.form['ques']})` and reading from it whenever the webage is opened